# getText() method of FlutterSummerNote returns blank on first button click

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a project that needs an integration of html editor, and I found interest about FlutterSummerNote package because of its interesting features. However, when I integrate it into my project, I am encountering an error regarding FlutterSummerNote package. When I clicked the Save button for the first time, I am getting blank value, but when I click the second time and so forth I can get the value from _keyEditor.currentState?.getText() method.  I am using `flutter_summernote: ^1.0.0` version. Below is the sample code. Any help please?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_summernote/flutter_summernote.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Demo Flutter Summernote'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GlobalKey<FlutterSummernoteState> _keyEditor = GlobalKey();
  String result = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        elevation: 0,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.save),
            onPressed: () async {
              final value = await _keyEditor.currentState?.getText();
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
                content: Text(value ?? "-"),
              ));
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: FlutterSummernote(
        hint: "Your text here...",
        key: _keyEditor,
        hasAttachment: true,
        customToolbar: """
          [
            ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
            ['insert', ['link', 'table', 'hr']]
          ]
        """,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by calling the function to get the text twice and consecutively as so:

```
final value = await _keyEditor.currentState?.getText();
final value = await _keyEditor.currentState?.getText();

ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
  duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
  content: Text(value ?? "-"),
));
```